# Remove Sunspot's fq parameter from Solr query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am using Sunspot for Rails, and I would like to remove the filter query from the Sunspot-generated Solr parameter (seen as `fq: ["type:Job"]`):

**Current**:

`SOLR Request [ path=select parameters={fq: ["type:Job"], q: "programmer", fl: "* score", qf: "Title", defType: "edismax", start: 0, rows: 30} ]`

**Desired**:

`SOLR Request [ path=select parameters={q: "programmer", fl: "* score", qf: "Title", defType: "edismax", start: 0, rows: 30} ]`

My model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :Title, :as => :Title
  end
```

I've read the ["manually adjusting Solr parameters"](http://sunspot.github.io/docs/index.html#Manually_Adjusting_Solr_Parameters) from the docs, but couldn't find any reference to actually *removing* the `fq` parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just use

```
Job.search do
 adjust_solr_params do |params|
   params.except! :fq
 end
end
```

Or something similiar in order to remove the :fq key from the params hash